# transferring data between two partially different ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two classes that I've populated with data. 
They are both similarly structured and both classes contain an ArrayList that have the *exact same* structure as the other class' ArrayList.

The ArrayLists are called `t30` and `tB` their structure is `(BigDecimal, String)`. Look in **main** for `new transactionB()` and `new Transaction30()` and it'll become more clear.

I want to do a **"transaction"** between these ArrayLists, so, moving (or copying&deleting) the values from ArrayList (`t30`) **to** ArrayList (`tB`)

TransactionO:

```
public class TransactionO{
    public ArrayList<TransactionB>tBpost = new ArrayList<TransactionB>();
    public TransactionO(/*constructor as seen in main...*/){/*stuff*/} ^
                                            //                         |
    public void addBPost(TransactionB b) { //                          |
        this.tBpost.add(b);               //adding ---------------------
    }
}
```

Transaction00:

```
public class Transaction00 {
    public ArrayList<Transaction30>t30post = new ArrayList<Transaction30>();
    public Transaction00(/*constructor as shown below*/){/*stuff*/}    ^
                                               //                      |
    public void add30Post(Transaction30 t30) {//                       |
        this.t30post.add(t30);               //adding ------------------
    }
}
```

Main:

```
TransactionO tO = null;
Transaction00 t00 = null;
private static List<TransactionO> allTransactionsIn = new ArrayList<TransactionO>();
private static List<Transaction00> allTransactionsOut = new ArrayList<Transaction00>();
//reading from file, parsing data, and finally storing the data in the class obj
tO = new TransactionO(accountNumber,currency, paymentDate,currentAmount,transactionQty);
tB = new TransactionB(amount,reference); //(BigDecimal, String)
tO.addBPost(tB);
// ^adding the class TransactionB into arraylist "tB" into TransactionO

t00 = new Transaction00(accountNumberSend,clrNrSend);
t30 = new Transaction30(amountSend,referenceSend); //(BigDecimal, String)
t00.add30Post(t30);     
// ^adding the class Transaction30 into arraylist "t30" into Transaction00

//finally
allTransactionsIn.add(tO);
allTransactionsOut.add(t00);
```

**Summary**:
In these ^ `allTransaction***` ArrayLists there are different class-objects but structurally-identical ArrayLists `(BigDecimal, String)`.

ASCII structure of arrayList `allTransactionsOut`:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| t00 (constructor-values) | t00.t30 (arrayList-values) | --------------copy
--------------------------------------------------------               |
Structurally different ^   |  Structurally same ^ (BigDecimal, String) |
```

ASCII structure of arrayList `allTransactionsIn`:

```
--------------------------------------------------------               |
| tO (constructor-values) | tO.tB (arrayList-values)    |  <------------
--------------------------------------------------------
Structurally different ^  |  Structurally same ^ (BigDecimal, String)
```

How would i transfer these `arrayList-values` from one list to another? (NOT `constructor-values`)

Please don't hesitate to ask if you need further explanation. Thanks

Comment: this is quite confusing to read. what do you mean by `ArrayList(BigDecimal, String)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner Sure, however, that doesn't work since the "constructor part" of my ArrayLists are different.

Comment: i think you should create a method to copy values from one array to another one by one

Comment: @PatrickParker Sorry about that. That's the structure of the "arraylists" tB and t30. Updated question, hopefully that clears it up for you.

Comment: have you considered using an `interface` for all these structural similarities? polymorphism

Comment: @PatrickParker There is an underlying `interface` to it all. (and to answer your question) I would if i could.

Comment: This isn't a MCVE. It's not minimal in the sense that it's very confusing (e.g., the names `O`, `00`, `B`, and `30` -- can you make the code read less like a tongue-twister?), and it's not complete because `amount` is not defined.

Comment: @pkpnd unfortunately - i have to agree with you. `amount` is 
 of type `BigDecimal` as you can see described in **main**. I think the ASCII example i gave is what you need to look at here so you wont get confused. The code is very confusing for an outsider, i get that. Refractoring everything would take very long time and i'll consider doing that if more people agree with you. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: what is stopping you from adding your methods ? I can see that code is all over, but that aside, what is the issue that is stopping you from adding a common`interface` and implement the `method`? also `TransactionO` and `Transaction00` has no `interface`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though `TransactionB` and `Transaction30` both happen to have fields of type `BigDecimal` and `String`, Java doesn't think they're related.

If you want to store both types in an `ArrayList`, then you'll need to make sure that both transaction types inherit from the same parent (either extend a common type, or implement a common interface).

e.g.

```
public abstract class ParentTransaction {
     protected BigDecimal value1
     protected String value2

     public ParentTransaction(BigDecimal value1, String value2) {
         this.value1 = value1;
         this.value2 = value2;
     }
}

public class TransactionB extends ParentTransaction {
   public TransactionB(BigDecimal amountSend, String referenceSend) {
       super(amountSend, referenceSend);
   }
   BigDecimal getAmountSend() {
       return value1;
   }
   String getReferenceSend() {
       return value2;
   }
}

public class Transaction30 extends ParentTransaction {
   public TransactionB(BigDecimal account, String reference) {
       super(account, reference);
   }
   BigDecimal getAccount() {
       return value1;
   }
   String getReference() {
       return value2;
   }
}
```